# GitHub API to Create a File

Tags: git, curl, github, github-api, http-put

So I'm trying to familiarize myself with the GitHub API. I'm using cURL commands to implement some of their basic functionality. I can get the basic authorization & repository creation correctly. Currently, I'm trying to create a file in a repository using their API & am facing the "message":"Not Found" error as the response.

Their [documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) suggests this:

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

I came up with this as the cURL equivalent:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: <token>' -d '{"path": "test.txt", "message": "Initial Commit", "committer": {"name": "<name>", "email": "<email>"}, "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM=", "note":"Test Commit"}' https://api.github.com/repos/InViN-test/test_repo1/contents/test.txt
```

I think the problem is with the API URL I'm using at the end, but I can't seem to figure out what the URL should look like.

This is what I used to create a repository:

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: <token>' -d '{"name": "test_repo1", "message": "Initial Commit", "committer": {"name": "<name>", "email": "<email>"}, "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM=", "note":"Test Commit"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

The repository creation URL I used follows: user/repos as the syntax.
Similarly, I've tried using user/repos/repo, but it didn't work.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

I've gone through various StackOverflow questions & many seem similar but none really offer an example so I can figure out where the mistake lies.

EDIT: Thanks to TimWolla for the answer.

Syntax of a working command to create a file in a repository using the GitHub API:

`curl -i -X PUT -H 'Authorization: token <token_string>' -d '{"path": "<filename.extension>", "message": "<Commit Message>", "committer": {"name": "<Name>", "email": "<E-Mail>"}, "content": "<Base64 Encoded>", "branch": "master"}' https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repository>/contents/<filename.extension>`

My example:

`curl -i -X PUT -H 'Authorization: token f94ce61613d5613a23770b324521b63d202d5645' -d '{"path": "test4.txt", "message": "Initial Commit", "committer": {"name": "Neil", "email": "neil@abc.com"}, "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM=", "branch": "master"}' https://api.github.com/repos/InViN-test/test_repo1/contents/test4.txt`

Comment: I had the same problem (404 when trying to create a file, while reading files was no problem at all) and in my case the solution was, that the Personal Access Token needed to have "admin:repo_hooks" in its scopes (additional to users and repos). It took me some time to find this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `curl` you need to specify the correct HTTP Verb (`PUT` in this case) using the `-X` option:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Authorization: …' yadayada
```

Also using your example payload an error 500 showed up, this shortened payload worked fine:

```
{"message": "Initial Commit","content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="}
```

I don't know the actual reason for the Server error, though.

Comment: TimWolla, what's the actual URL that you used for the PUT command?

Comment: @Neil The same as you did, except for a repository of mine: `https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/contents/so-test.txt`

Comment: Can you paste the complete command? I'm still getting a "message":"Not Found" error.

Comment: @Neil Sure: `curl -X PUT -H 'Authorization: token yadayada' -d '{"message": "Initial Commit","content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="}' https://api.github.com/repos/user/test/contents/so-test.txt`

Comment: Tim, thanks! It works as expected now. I'm using the following command:
`curl -i -X PUT -H 'Authorization: <token>' -d '{"path": "test4.txt", "message": "Initial Commit", "committer": {"name": "<name>", "email": "<email>"}, "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM=", "branch": "master"}' https://api.github.com/repos/InViN-test/test_repo1/contents/test4.txt`

Comment: I was wondering why there is a `path` in the required parameters.

Comment: I suppose if your file is in a different directory than where you're executing?