# How can I use UrlFetchApp in Google Apps Script to update a Github repo?

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, http-headers, github-api

Salutations - I'm trying to use the Github API to update a file which I'm generating in Google Apps Script. I'm displaying the file (an image) on a Github page. Unfortunately my knowledge of the Github API and of HTTP requests are poor.

How would I configure `UrlFetchApp` to commit a file to my Github repo? I think a similar idea is expressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312545/github-api-to-create-a-file) but I don't know how to translate it accurately to Apps Script and I'm finding it hard to debug against the API. Very grateful for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### From:

If you want to convert the following curl command of this thread to Google Apps Script,

```
curl -i -X PUT \
  -H 'Authorization: token <token_string>' \
  -d '{"path": "<filename.extension>", "message": "<Commit Message>", "committer": {"name": "<Name>", "email": "<E-Mail>"}, "content": "<Base64 Encoded>", "branch": "master"}' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repository>/contents/<filename.extension>
```

#### To:

it becomes as follows.

```
function myFunction() {
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID you want to upload here.
  const content = Utilities.base64Encode(DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getBytes());
  const url = "https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repository>/contents/<filename.extension>";
  const data = {"path": "<filename.extension>", "message": "<Commit Message>", "committer": {"name": "<Name>", "email": "<E-Mail>"}, "content": content, "branch": "master"};
  const params = {
    method: "put",
    payload: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      authorization: `token <token_string>`,
      // Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3+json"  // Even when this is not used, the request works.
    }
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

- About `<filename.extension>`, for example, when you want to put `sample.txt` to the under the directory of `./sample`, please use the URL like `https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repository>/contents/sample/sample.txt`.

#### Note:

- In this case, your token is required to be able to be used. So please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Create or update file contents](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents)