# Using curl for pushing a file to GitHub repository

Tags: curl, github-pages, github-api, gitlab-api

I want to create (push) new file on the GitHub repository without `git` tools, (because the `git` tool doesn't available on my `PHP` host). So I had a little research and I found [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest).

I try to use `curl` with personal access token to upload or modify a file on my repo. [here is](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aborruso/40aee4f1738c0a0e3727bf7cbec91152/raw/9458c7ff7e5402bb404e2e1fd29a3bb5dd6f162d/updatefile.sh) a shell code that I found and made my changes to `curl` like below:

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/newFile.txt -X PUT 
\ -H 'Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -d "{\"path\": \"newFile.txt\", 
\ \"message\": \"update\", \"content\": \"$(openssl base64 -A -in newFile.txt)\", \"branch\": 
\"master\",
\ \"sha\": $(curl -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/newFile.txt  | jq .sha)}"
```

but I get this error:

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
>
> Server: GitHub.com

How I can fix this?

P.S. even if there is an `push file by email` service on GitHub or (GitLab), this can help to create file on my repo via e-mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the "[Create or update file contents](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents)" endpoint API:

```
PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}
```

(I don't see `contents` in your `https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/newFile.txt` URL)

Make sure to use a recent PAT (Personal Access Token), as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22312545/6309).
And [an example](https://gist.github.com/aborruso/40aee4f1738c0a0e3727bf7cbec91152):

```
#! /bin/bash
 
cartella= " /var/myfolder "
 
# update the file
curl -i -X ​​PUT -H ' Authorization: token 4d013330xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ' -d " { \" path \" : \" mattei.csv \" , \
\" message \" : \" update \" , \" content \" : \" $( openssl base64 -A -in $cartella /mattei.csv ) \" , \" branch \" : \" master \" , \
\" sha \" : $( curl -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/contents/mattei.csv | jq .sha ) } " \
https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/contents/mattei.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

I put my working `curl` here, if someone need this.

For easy push, it's better make your file in **base64** format (`base64 {filename}` or [online tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=make%20file%20in%20base64%20online)) and then:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}/{fileName} -d "{\"message\":\"your commit message\",\"content\":\"your file in BASE64\"}"
```